# How do I allow all subseqent threads to continue through a "gate"

Tags: c#, concurrency

I need to be able to make number of threads wait on a semaphore but when I release them, no other thread should wait on that semaphore again - it should just allow any subsequent threads. I can't find any examples of this.

Here is an example. I need to allow all the reads of the "Result" property after it's set (not just allow one read).

```
private class TaskResultWrapper<T>
    {
        private T result;

        private SemaphoreSlim valueSetSemaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(0, 1);
        private CancellationToken cancellationToken;

        public TaskResultWrapper(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            this.cancellationToken = cancellationToken;
        }

        public T Result
        {
            get {
                valueSetSemaphore.Wait(cancellationToken);
                return result;
            }

            set
            {
                result = value;
                valueSetSemaphore.Release();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you talk us through why you want this solution? What is the underlying business problem?

Comment: I actually think you'd be better off using a `TaskCompletionSource` (as per my answer) rather than writing your own class and using `ManualResetEvent`, but this might depend on your use-cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you use [ManualResetEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.manualresetevent?view=netframework-4.7.2). It is designed just for that.
All threads that call WaitOne() on the manual-reset-event instance will be blocked until the manual-reset-event is signaled by calling Set(). Then, all blocked threads are released.

Comment: In my case Ii had to use [ManualResetEventSlim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.manualreseteventslim?view=netframework-4.7.2) which supports unified cancellation (cancellation tokens)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're reinventing the wheel here with your `TaskResultWrapper`.
It looks like you could actually use a [`TaskCompletionSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcompletionsource-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) to do this.

Note that this also supports cancellation. Here's an example:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp10
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var test = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();

            Task.Run(() => Parallel.Invoke(
                () => printValue(test.Task),
                () => printValue(test.Task),
                () => printValue(test.Task)));

            Console.WriteLine("Tasks are all waiting on the value; press return to continue.");
            Console.ReadLine();

            test.SetResult(42); // Or test.SetCanceled() to cancel it.

            Console.WriteLine("Set result to 42 (or cancelled)");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void printValue(Task<int> task)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine(task.Result);
            }

            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Task received exception: " + exception.InnerException.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Try running this as-is, and then try after changing the `test.SetResult(42)` to `test.SetCanceled()`

Comment: For this case, you are completely right. Thank you for this solution.